# How to delete Task created on Task.Factory.StartNew

Tags: c#, .net, task

I use following code to create task.

But seems like when application closes, the `Task` is still in memory...

How to delete Task created on Task.Factory.StartNew properly?

Thanks!

```
class Service()

 Task job;

void DoJob()
{

job = (Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                  {

                      try
                      {


                      }
                      catch (Exception ex)
                      {

                      }


                  }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent));
            }
```

Comment: How do you see that the Task is still in memory ? Is the Process still listed ? 

When the Process is terminated all threads and objects within it are also.

If the Process is still isted are you sure this doesnt also happen without the Task?

Comment: @BoasEnkler When I close application I cannot see EXE in TaskManager but at the same moment I cannot delete that EXE from the folder sometimes.

Comment: Ok Perhaps there are just some haning file handles. you could use FileMon to observe who is locking the file. These hanging file handles often disappear after some seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a process exits the OS frees all resources held by that process. All memory is freed. This cleanup procedure is very reliable. You can assume that the memory held by your task is cleaned up properly.

What ever you saw - you misinterpreted it.

Comment: When I close application I cannot see EXE in TaskManager but at the same moment I cannot delete that EXE from the folder sometimes.

Comment: @ClarkKent why do you think this has something to do with memory? Ask a new question: "Why can't I delete my exe after it has exited?"

Comment: @Clark Kent: If you want to see what process has an open handle to the file you can use a tool called Process Explorer.  It's part of the Systinternals suite: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062

Answer (score 1):

By default, `Task` is running as a background thread which means that your `Task` should be vanished upon application exit.

Comment: Tasks *creating using `Task.Run`*, are executed in a background thread (specifically, a thread pool thread).

Answer (score 0):

A Task contains a WaitHandle which is IDisposable. As consequence the Task is also IDisposable and need disposed if you don't need it anymore.

But you have to Dispose the Task only if you realy access the WaitHandle of the Task directly (.NET 4.5). Prior with .NET 4.0 you have to call dispose when you call one of the Waitx() methods or the handle directly.

But IDisposable has no influence when the object is cleanup from memory. This is the job of  the garbage collection and let the garbabe collection do his work.

Comment: Even this is irrelevant when the entire process exits.  it doesn't matter if the object is disposed or not, the memory will be reclaimed regardless.

Comment: Maybe irrelevant here, but it's good to know when you work with task and wondering why the Task is IDisposable.

Comment: If you would like to share some information that you think is helpful, but that does not answer the question that is asked, you should be posting a comment, or possibly even finding a question to which the information is on topic, rather than posting an answer merely to discuss an offtopic tangent.

Comment: Sorry Servy, I answer the question 'How to delete Task created on Task.Factory.StartNew' with this post. Do nothing the let the garbage collection do his job. If somebody read the question, he may find this answer usefull.